# why is my fade in and out timer not working

Tags: jquery

can someone tell me why the default fade time not working if i change right at the bottom? i need to make it fade even slower but i just do not understand why it just wont work.

here is the js

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.tickerme = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.tickerme.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

      var ticker = $(this);
      // SVG definitions for the play/pause/previous/next controls:
      var control_definitions = '<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="224" height="32" viewBox="0 0 224 32"><defs><g id="icon-play"><path class="path1" d="M6 4l20 12-20 12z"></path></g><g id="icon-pause"><path class="path1" d="M4 4h10v24h-10zM18 4h10v24h-10z"></path></g><g id="icon-prev"><path class="path1" d="M18 5v10l10-10v22l-10-10v10l-11-11z"></path></g><g id="icon-next"><path class="path1" d="M16 27v-10l-10 10v-22l10 10v-10l11 11z"></path></g></defs></svg>';
      var control_styles = '<style type="text/css">#ticker_container{width:100%}#newscontent{float:left}#news{display:none}#controls{float:right;height:16px}.icon{display:inline-block;width:16px;height:16px;fill:' + opts.control_colour + '}.icon:hover{fill:' + opts.control_rollover + '}</style>';
      // Array to contain news contents:
      var contents = [];
      var position = -1;
      var timer;

      init();

      /* Initialise */

      function init() {

        // Hide all:
        $(ticker).hide();

        // Create the buttons:
        $('body').prepend(control_definitions).prepend(control_styles);

        var controls = '<div id="ticker_container">';
        controls += '<div id="newscontent"><div id="news"></div></div>';
        controls += '<div id="controls">';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="pause_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-pause" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-pause"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="play_trigger" style="display:none"><svg class="icon icon-play" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-play"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="prev_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-prev" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-prev"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '<a href="#" id="next_trigger"><svg class="icon icon-next" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-next"></use></svg></a>';
        controls += '</div>';
        controls += '</div>';
        $(controls).insertAfter(ticker);

        // Load up the array:
        $(ticker).children().each(function(i) {
          contents[i] = ($(this).html());
        });

        load_container();
      }

      /* load_container */

      function load_container() {

        if (position == (contents.length - 1)) {
          position = 0;
        } else {
          position++;
        }
        // Fade out the current item, replace it with the next one, and fade it in:
        if (opts.type == 'fade') {
          $('#news').fadeOut(opts.fade_speed, function() {
            $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news">' + contents[position] + '</div>');
            $('#news').fadeIn(opts.fade_speed);
          });
        }
        timer = setTimeout(load_container, opts.duration);
      }

      /* Control functions */

      $('a#pause_trigger').click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).hide();
        $('#play_trigger').show();
        return false;
      });

      $('a#play_trigger').click(function() {
        load_container();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#pause_trigger').show();
        return false;
      });

      $('a#prev_trigger').click(function() {
        if (position == 0) {
          position = (contents.length - 1);
        } else {
          position--;
        }
        $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news" style="display:block">' + contents[position] + '</div>');
        if (opts.auto_stop) $('a#pause_trigger').trigger('click');
        return false;
      });

      $('a#next_trigger').click(function() {
        if (position == (contents.length - 1)) {
          position = 0;
        } else {
          position++;
        }
        $('#newscontent').html('<div id="news" style="display:block">' + contents[position] + '</div>');
        if (opts.auto_stop) $('a#pause_trigger').trigger('click');
        return false;
      });

    });

  };

  $.fn.tickerme.defaults = {
    fade_speed: 600,
    duration: 50000,
    auto_stop: true,
    type: 'fade',
    control_colour: '#333333',
    control_rollover: '#666666'
  };

}(jQuery));

$("div").tickerme();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test</div>
```

the above code seems to be fast and no matter me changing the default values it just wont take any affect? is there anywhere else in the code i could set the time for it to fade slow or fast?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by *if i change right at the bottom* - if you change your `.defaults={fade_speed:6000,...` then the fade speed changes fine.  It also works if you provide as an option: `$("div").tickerme({fade_speed:6000});`

Comment: I've converted your code sample to a snippet.  In doing so, I've had to assume how it's being called `$("div").tickerme();`.  Please update the snippet to *demonstrate* your problem.  See [mcve].